# CentOS network interfaces are not coming up

Tags: centos, networking, hp

We installed a fresh copy of CentOS on "HP Proliant DL380p Gen8" and the ethernet interfaces are having this Strange, fluctuating connectivity issue where the interfaces either work with no issues and or are completely dead.

Here are some commands outputs:

**Systemctl status network**

```
network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-04-15 03:38:16 EDT; 3min 18s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6557 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 15 03:38:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Apr 15 03:38:15 localhost.localdomain network[6557]: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Apr 15 03:38:15 localhost.localdomain network[6557]: Bringing up interface eno1:  ERROR     : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth] Device eno1 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization.
Apr 15 03:38:15 localhost.localdomain network[6557]: [FAILED]
Apr 15 03:38:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 15 03:38:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Apr 15 03:38:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Apr 15 03:38:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: network.service failed.
```

**ifconfg -a**

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**ip a**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**lspci -nn|grep net**

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657] (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657] (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657] (rev 01)
03:00.3 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657] (rev 01)
```

**Ip link**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

**nmcli c**

```
NAME  UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
eno1  2c3315f0-9a56-4c6f-9cab-a55e3a0f7f2d  ethernet  --   
eno2  657324ea-5e27-4d31-a6ce-314227330869  ethernet  --     
eno3  6c53e522-01ce-4807-bfe1-46266cb45e29  ethernet  --     
eno4  e7cebe37-3d20-4e34-b951-ea5901c36a1c  ethernet  --
```

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1**

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
PROXY_METHOD="none"
BROWSER_ONLY="no"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="eno1"
UUID="2c3315f0-9a56-4c6f-9cab-a55e3a0f7f2d"
DEVICE="eno1"
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=2c:76:8a:5d:ea:b8
```

**nmcli device status**

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

**nmcli device status**

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

**lspci -vv**

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Q4yrWac1)

**journalctl -b 0 | grep devices**

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/w2WFnW0r)

**journalctl -b 0 | grep kernel**

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/zM37wnVa)

**journalctl -b 0 | grep module**

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/AwE8YXiE)

Comment: By "fluctuating" are you saying that the interfaces sometimes work and sometimes don't? Across reboots? Or do they work intermittently while the system is up and nothing relevant is changing? You may also want to look at/share the output of `lspci -vv` (which drivers/modules are in use? There may be known issues with them), `nmcli device status` and/or `nmcli device show` (there may be recognized but not configured devices) and `journalctl -b 0 | grep <devices' kernel module>` to see if your devices are being renamed on boot.

Comment: No I mean the latter, it's across boots. The commands doesn't even list network interfaces. I am sorry I am new and I couldn't pick the last bit of `journalctl` command so I ran devices, kernel and module separately.

I also updated the question with new logs, you can check. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Strange enough, the verbose `lspci` you posted has no references to network interfaces, contrasting with the output of `lspci -nn|grep net`. Also, no mention of network interfaces in `journalctl -b 0 | grep kernel` (nor of bus/device numbers `03:00.`) may suggest that the hardware is not properly seen/recognized.

Comment: Thanks for looking, are you suggesting that there may be driver issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm no expert here. I'm just saying that the `03.00.x` (parts of) PCI addresses should be in `journalctl -b 0 | grep kernel` regardless of any driver, since the kernel logs them even before the proper drivers kick in. And since they are not there, we may be seeing a hardware issue (or a hardware configuration issue).

Answer (score 0):

Centos normally comes with networking disabled unless you manually enable when installing. if your physical network links are connected properly and you can check links using `ip link` command. you can set line `ONBOOT=no` to `ONBOOT=yes` in each interface configuration found in below path.

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-xxxx
```

And you can get more information by typing `nmcli c` command if this is newer centos 7.x

Answer (score 0):

rename interface file name.

```
mv ifcfg-en01 ifcfg-eno1
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my question the interface file is named `ifcfg-eno1` already.

Comment: you can try ifup command.
    ifup eno1

Comment: Tried that many times, doesn't work.